# Airflow DAG scheduled monthly not queued

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an Airflow DAG set up to run monthly (with the @monthly time_interal). The next dag runs seem to be scheduled but they don't appear as "queued" in the Airflow UI. I don't understant because everythink seems good otherwise. Here is how my DAG is configured :

```
with DAG(
    "dag_name",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@monthly",
    catchup=True,
    default_args={"retries": 5, "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1)},
) as dag:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get no runs at all when you unpause your DAG or one that is being backfilled and it says Last run `2023-01-01, 00:00:00`?

In the latter case Airflow is behaving as intended, the run that just happened was the one that would have actually been queued and ran at midnight on `2023-02-01`. :)

I used your configuration on a new simple DAG and it gave me one backfilled successful run with the run ID `scheduled__2023-01-01T00:00:00+00:00` so running for the data interval `2023-01-01` (`logical_date`) to `2023-02-01`, which means the Run that would have actually been queued at midnight on `2023-02-01`.

[image: DAG in overview]

The next run is scheduled for the logical date `2023-02-01` which means for the data from `2023-02-01` to `2023-03-01`. This run will only actually be queued and happen at midnight `2023-03-01` as the `Run After` date shows:

[image: Run After]

[This guide](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/scheduling-in-airflow) might help with terminology Airflow uses around schedules.

I'm assuming you wanted the DAG to backfill two runs, one that would have happened on `2023-01-01` and one that would have happened on `2023-02-01`. This DAG should do that:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

with DAG(
    "dag_name_3",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 1),
    schedule_interval="@monthly",
    catchup=True,
    default_args={"retries": 5, "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1)},
) as dag:

    t1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t1")
```

Comment: Thank you very much with your answer, it really helps me. I thought that my DAG that will run in 2023-03-01, 00:00:00 shoud be queued from now, but actually it is just scheduled and will be queued and run at 2023-01-01, 00:00:00.